# When onChange event is fired in the checkbox type input?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, event-handling

According to MDN,
When a < input type="checkbox">  element is checked or unchecked (by clicking or using the keyboard); the change event is fired.
[link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event)

But I did not understand how this react code works.
The below react code seems like the onChange event is firing even before the checkbox state changes.

Any explanation of when precisely the onChange event is fired when the input is checkbox?

```
export default function(){
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
    const handleCheck = () => {
    setChecked(~checked);
    };  

    return <div>
          <input checked={checked} onChange={handleCheck}. type="checkbox"/>
     </div>
}
```

Comment: `The below react code seems like the onChange event is firing even before the checkbox state changes.` How did you come to this assumption?

Comment: @NeERAJTK Run the above code without the onChange attribute you cannot change the checkbox state, but when you include the onChange event with the function above the checkbox state changes.

Comment: [Read about controlled and uncontrolled input here](https://www.altogic.com/blog/difference-between-controlled-and-uncontrolled-component#:~:text=%E2%80%8B,the%20state%20of%20the%20component.)

Comment: onChange in React is actually mapped to onInput, but the controlled/uncontrolled link above is the overarching issue.

Answer (score 0):

it is the example of controlled input. initially the checkbox will unchecked because of the state's initial state which is false and if he click on checkbox then it will be checked because of handleCheck() event which simply inverts the state's value to true/false.